# php import csv special char issue

Tags: php, csv, encoding, char

I am trying to import CSV in php by 'fgetcsv()' function, but the CSV file has some hidden characters, these character as not showing in Excel or notepad, i can see only one char in browser console.

[image]

i have tried to remove these characters by `trim()`, `utf8_decode()` as well `preg_replace()` but no solution has coming up.

```
trim($value, ' \t\n\r\0\x0B\x00..\x1F\x09\0x0A');
preg_replace($value, '/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $value);
```

And finally, I am facing issue in following [CSV file](http://13.126.68.248/book1.csv), please provide a solution, how i can rid red dot(.) char in import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though this has a Byte Order Marker for UTF8 (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file.  You can remove it by using...

```
if ( substr($value,0,3) === chr(239).chr(187).chr(191))    {
    $value = substr($value, 3);
}
```

or

```
$value = trim($value, chr(239).chr(187).chr(191));
```